# Spring - Injecting a HashMap<Class, List<X>> from XML

Tags: spring

Right now, I have a class called A that contains an attribute like this one:

```
private Map<Class<?>, List<EntityIndexConfig>> relatedEntitiesMap;
```

My initial idea was to inject a few keys with their respective list from the XML but could not make it work. Instead I created a method with @PostConstruct:

```
@PostConstruct @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public void loadRelatedEntities() {
   /* And here I load it */
   relatedEntitiesMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<EntityIndexConfig>>(){{
       put(Agency.class, new ArrayList<EntityIndexConfig>() {{
           add(new EntityIndexConfig("Package.listByAgency", applicationContext.getBean(PackageRepository.class), "agencyId"));
       }});
       /* More entries here... */
   }
}
```

Despite it works, I would like to be able to have this configuration in the Spring XML file if possible. Any ideas how to create a Map and put classes as keys and a list of EntityIndexConfig?s?

If any of you knows I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map) in the documentation:

```
<util:map key-type="java.lang.Class">  
        <entry key="com.MyClass">  
            <util:list>  
              <ref bean="EntityIndexConfig1"/>  
              <bean class="com.mypackage.SomeEntityIndexConfig/>  
            </util:list>  
        </entry> 
</util:map>
```

This assumes you have declared the `util` namespace prefix:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

Please keep in mind I wrote this freehand, and it is quite possible I made a typo or syntax error somewhere. But this should get you very close at least.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually ended up using a mix between this answer and the one from @kungfuters. The basic difference is that instead of referencing the beans inside the list, I created them with the constructor-arg element. Anyways thanks! It's working and doesn't look as bad as creating everything separately and referencing every bean. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
<bean class="yourpackage.A">
    <property name="relatedEntitiesMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="yourpackage.Agency">
                <list>
                    <bean class="yourpackage.EntityIndexConfig">
                        <constructor-arg value="Package.listByAgency"/>
                        <constructor-arg ref="packageRepository" />
                        <constructor-arg value="agencyId" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="packageRepository" class="yourpackage.PackageRepository" />
```

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned, I ended up using a mix of your answer and the one from @Vidya and it worked perfectly. What we are missing here is the key-type="java.lang.Class" for the map element. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, when I ran a test, Spring's default converters converted the key to a Class as expected, but no matter...glad it's working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

You can define beans and reference them as keys and values if you want, but if you ask me it's overkill:

```
<bean id="listElementBean"/>
<bean id="keyBean" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
    <constructor-arg value="com.MyClass"/>
</bean>
<bean id="valueBean" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="listElementBean" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<util:map>
    <entry key-ref="keyBean">
        <ref bean="valueBean" />
    </entry>
</util:map>
```